# Exception on settings Custom document properties of excel workbook

Tags: c#, excel, exception, vsto

I am working on an excel VSTO add-in, in thie add-in I structure some worksheets to process them later. I want to know later when the user open and excel workbook if the workbook was structured with my add-in or not to do some processing on it. To this end I try to used CustomDocumentProperties.

I am facing two problems :

- The visual studio debugger don't evaluate the children of DocumentProperties variables, I can't inspect them.
- When I try to create a new DocumentPropertiy by calling DocumentProperties.Add I get an ArgumentException stating the the value does not fall in range.

Function called to structure the workbook:

```
public void InitWorkbook()
{
    workingBook = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(Application.ActiveWorkbook);
    var dps = (DocumentProperties)workingBook.CustomDocumentProperties;
    if (!customDocumentPropertyExist("validctcwb", dps))
    {
          // some sheet creation and listobject creation    
          dps.Add("validctcwb", false);
    }
}

bool customDocumentPropertyExist(string name, DocumentProperties dps)
{
     foreach (DocumentProperty p in dps)
     {
         if (p.Name == name)
         {
              return true;
         }
     }
     return false;
}
```

Thank you in advance for your valuable help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm doing the same in my Addin to generate a unique Id.

```
var propertyName = "validctcwb";
var propertyValue = false;
var propertyType = MsoDocProperties.msoPropertyTypeBoolean;
dps.Add(propertyName, false, propertyType, propertyValue);
```

If you wish to see the values while debuging, you can introduce the following method:

```
public static IEnumerable<CustomProperty> GetCustomDocumentProperties(Workbook workbook)
{
    foreach (CustomProperty property in workbook.CustomDocumentProperties)
    {
        yield return property;
    }
}
```

Voilà

Comment: Thank you for the answer, no it works just fine. The propertyValue are not optional parameter for the Add method ? why need I to provide them in order to add the property ?.

Comment: When `linkToContent`(second argument) is `false` then the value is required. If `true` then `linkSource` is required. See MSDN : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.core.documentproperties.add.aspx